# Get angular 2 service inside a custom class instantiated by me

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, angular2-directives

Im building an angular 2 app, and i need a way to get a reference to a service/class that is injected/instantiated by angular framework.

I have a generic class...lets call it **Custom** class, that i use throughout the site. This class, however is instantiated by me, not angular 2.
Now, i need to use some of the services instantiated by angular 2 inside that class.

i.e

```
// this is not angular component/service
export default class Custom {

    constructor(properties) {

    }
    doSomething() {
        // UserService is a service that is injected into other componetns constructors, but this class is not a component.
        // Here i need a ref to the singleton 'UserService' made by angular
        let userService = someAngularFunction.getInstance('UserService');
        userService.doIt();
    }

}

// in some component.
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    doAnotherThing() {
       let c = new Custom('some generic params');
       c.doSomething();
    }
}
// in some n number of other components, repeat the above.
```

Note, i know that i could inject the '**UserService**' into 
**MyComponent**, and from **MyComponent**, pass it down to **new Custom()** constructor. But, since MyComponent itself doesn't use that service, and

**Custom** class is instantiated in many other places, id like to move that dependency into Custom class.

Is there a way to do that ?
If not, whats the second best option.

Comment: May I ask why the Custom class can't be an Angular service as well?

Comment: Custom class is basically a Model with various functions, like save(), update(), sort() etc

These models are created in a service, after some content is loaded from the server.
e.g a contentService loads a list of post( raw data ), and builds 
ContentModels from the raw data.
Then, these content models are provided to components through observable subscriptions.

in some component i can do this.
contentService.load().subscribe( (posts) => {
    this.posts = posts;
})

And in some component functions i'd do
this.posts[3].save()
or in template (click)="post.delete()"
etc

Comment: It seems it still could be an Angular service?

Comment: You may be able to use `@Inject(UserService) private userService` in the constructor of the class, although I'm not sure on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you have two choices:

1) Manually pass the service into the Custom class constructor.

```
let x = new Custom(this.userService);
```

2) Make the Custom class a service as well. Then it will participate in Angular's DI.

See this article for more information: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html